# css horizontal scroll query

Tags: html, css, scroll

so i'm trying to have a horizontal scroll for a menu div for mobile and i'm using http://jsfiddle.net/v2Ypj/ and it seemed fairly straight forward so i used

```css
.submenu .right.horizontal {
  height:160px;
  width: 700px !important;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

it worked scrolling only that div vertically (till i figured out i needed to change the width) but for some reason it won't work horizontally. the bar doesn't even show up. here's the website i'm testing on.
http://www.embroiderywear.com/test/responsivetest/index2.html
any help would appreciate any help!

Comment: Why on earth would you want it to do this? Why not just wrap it with flexbox and make it actually responsive?

Comment: @Option True that !

Comment: never heard of flexbox before honestly

Comment: @Felicyia I'd suggest looking into it, it's very easy to pickup as it is CSS based and means you can make everything mobile friendly rather than adding a scroll to everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around in the inspector and came up with this solution:

```
.submenu .right.horizontal {
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.submenu .right a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

Your width was set to a hard pixel amount (700px). By setting the width to 100% it allows the content to overflow properly. The styles for the A tag pervents your links from wrapping, hence making the area scrollable.

I would suggest putting the above styles in a media query.

Comment: this 10000% worked! thank you! i figured i had to set the area otherwise it would take the 100% width as the screen width and then overflow-y. that's y i set the hard 700px. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one, hope this will help

http://jsfiddle.net/vUEYG/

**HTML**

```
<div id="containersimg">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 110px;
}

#containersimg {
   background-color: #bbb;
   width: 300px;
   height: 135px;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}

.square {
   background-color: #00b;
   float: left;
   height: 90px;
   width: 90px;
   margin: 5px;
}
```